# collectd not able to send data to graphite carbon daemon

Tags: graphite, collectd

We have a graphite full stack server which receives metrics from different machines. While other collectd client are sending data fine, one of the client is giving the below error:

> Jan 29 23:24:44 collectd-client collectd[25489]: write_graphite plugin: send
>   to graphite-server:2003 ((null)) failed with status -1 (Connection
>   refused) Jan 29 23:24:44 collectd-client collectd[25489]: collectd: Stopping
>   5 write threads.

```
collectd.conf as below
LoadPlugin syslog
LoadPlugin cpu
LoadPlugin df
LoadPlugin disk
LoadPlugin interface
LoadPlugin load
LoadPlugin memory
LoadPlugin rrdtool
LoadPlugin write_graphite
<Plugin df>
        MountPoint "/"
</Plugin>
<Plugin disk>
        Disk "/^[hs]d[a-f][0-9]?$/"
</Plugin>
<Plugin interface>
        Interface "eth0"
</Plugin>
<Plugin write_graphite>
  <Node "carbon">
    Host "sde-graphite"
    Port "2003"
    Prefix "collectd"
    Postfix "collectd"
    StoreRates true
    AlwaysAppendDS false
    EscapeCharacter "_"
  </Node>
</Plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify whether carbon is running in host sde-graphite at port 2003. you can do a netstat and see if there is a **UDP listener** at 2003. I guess, it is not running.

Comment: great, its listening on tcp not udp. inside <plugin write_graphite> i added "protocol tcp". now i can see graphs in web interface

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

I had the same issue, my metrics are always working but randomly some nodes stop sending metrics. And collectd shows the same error:

> Jun 18 15:04:23 node-a collectd[20235]: write_graphite plugin: send to 10.8.0.100:2003 (udp) failed with status -1 (Invalid argument)
>
> Jun 18 15:04:23 node-a collectd[20235]: Filter subsystem: Built-in target `write': Dispatching value to all write plugins failed with status -1.

The daemon is still alive but not sending metrics to graphite.
NOTE: My nodes send data to graphite trough an openvpn tunnel.

It seems to be a connection timeout error against the graphite server. I can reproduce the error by stopping/interrupting vpn service and immediately collectd shows the error above.

Hope it helps
Enjoy!